# Can a solid object gain speed instantly?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, speed

Is it possible for a solid *real world* object to instantly gain speed without having to accelerate from $v = 0 \, \text{m/s}$ to $v = 1000\,\text{m/s}$, or does it have to accelerate in order to reach that speed? In other words (after some feedback from comments) is infinite acceleration physical?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Remember your kinematics equations, especially $v_f=v_i+a\Delta t$

Comment: Your question can be read as asking if a solid *real world* object can change speed without changing speed.  Is this what you intend to ask?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri No, do excuse my English. I am wondering if a stationary object with a speed of 0 m/s can instantly gain speed of 1000 m/s, by any means possible. So the time passed between it's speed of 0 m/s and 1000 m/s is 0.

Comment: You're asking if infinite acceleration is physical?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I am asking if there must be an acceleration between 0 m/s and 1000m/s. Can object's speed **instantly** jump to 1000 m/s, without going through the entire range of speeds [0-1000]?

Comment: Then you *are* asking if infinite acceleration is physical.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I guess I am. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Any solid real world object obeys the laws of classical physics. It is impossible for a solid real world object to gain speed without accelerating.

Consider the example of a car. The only ways to reach higher speeds in the car is if the driver steps on the gas pedal very hard or a collision with another object (like a moving car) such that the force exerted on it causes it to accelerate to a higher speed (via F = ma and kinematic equations). There is no force (nor gas pedal) strong enough to instantaneously change the speed of the car to its final speed from its initial speed.

Now consider another example. Just because light traveling over a short period of time appears to travel instantaneously to a nearby observer does not mean that light travels infinitely fast. Similarly, just because an object appears to have a much greater final speed relative to its initial speed does not mean that the object instantaneously reached its final velocity, but rather that it accelerated by a large finite amount over a short finite time interval.

Answer (score 0):

Kinematics equation for velocity is v=u+at which clearly states that without any acceleration v=u,so the speed will be same.